# Category Tree extraction in Wikipedia using Java

Tags: java, web-crawler, deadlock, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Basically I intend to extract the entire category tree in Wikipedia under the root node "Economics" using Wikipedia API sandbox. I don't need the content of the articles, I just need few basic details like pageid, title, revision history (at some later stage of my work). As of now I can extract it level by level but what I want is a recursive/iterative function which does it.
Each category contains a categories and articles (like each root contains nodes and leaves). 
I wrote one code to extract the first level into files. one file contains the articles, second folder contains the name of categories (daughters of the root which can be further sub-classified).
Then I went into level and extracted their categories and articles and sub-categories using similar code.
The code remains similar in each case but its the scalability. I need to reach the lowest leaves of all nodes. So i need a recursion which continuously checks till the end.
I labelled files which contains categories as 'c_', so I can provide the condition while extracting different levels. 
Now for some reason it has entered into a deadlock and keeps adding same things again and again. I need a way out of the deadlock.

```
package wikiCrawl;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.json.CDL;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class SubCrawl 
{
public static void  main(String[] args)   throws IOException, InterruptedException, JSONException 
{   File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Root/Economics_2.txt"); 
    crawlfile(file);    
}

public static void crawlfile(File food) throws JSONException, IOException ,InterruptedException
{           
    ArrayList<String> cat_list =new ArrayList <String>();
            Scanner scanner_cat = new Scanner(food);
            scanner_cat.useDelimiter("\n");
            while (scanner_cat.hasNext())
            {
                String scan_n = scanner_cat.next();
                if(scan_n.indexOf(":")>-1)
                    cat_list.add(scan_n.substring(scan_n.indexOf(":")+1));              
            }

            System.out.println(cat_list);

            //get the categories in different languages
            URL category_json; 
            for (int i_cat=0; i_cat<cat_list.size();i_cat++)
            {           
                category_json = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3A"+cat_list.get(i_cat).replaceAll(" ", "%20").trim()+"&cmlimit=500"); //.trim() removes trailing and following whitespaces
                System.out.println(category_json);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) category_json.openConnection(); //Opens the connection to the URL so clients can communicate with the resources.
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(category_json.openStream()));

                String line;
                String diff = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    diff=diff+line; 
                }
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                reader.close();

                JSONArray jsonarray_cat = new JSONArray (diff.substring(diff.indexOf("[{\"pageid\"")));
                System.out.println(jsonarray_cat);
                //Loop categories
                for (int i_url = 0; i_url<jsonarray_cat.length();i_url++) //jSONarray is an array of json objects, we are looping through each object
                {

                    //Get the URL _part (Categorie isn't correct)
                    int pageid=Integer.parseInt(jsonarray_cat.getJSONObject(i_url).getString("pageid"));  //this can be written in a much better way
                    System.out.println(pageid);
                    String title=jsonarray_cat.getJSONObject(i_url).getString("title");
                    System.out.println(title);                      

                    File food_year= new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Root/"+cat_list.get(i_cat).replaceAll(" ", "_").trim()+".txt");
                    File food_year2= new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Root/c_"+cat_list.get(i_cat).replaceAll(" ", "_").trim()+".txt");
                    food_year.createNewFile();
                    food_year2.createNewFile();

                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(food_year, true)));
                    BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(food_year2, true)));               

                    if (title.contains("Category:"))
                    {
                        writer2.write(pageid+";"+title);
                        writer2.newLine();
                        writer2.flush();
                        crawlfile(food_year2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writer.write(pageid+";"+title);
                        writer.newLine();
                        writer.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: For starters this might be too big a demand on the wikimedia servers. There are over a million categories (https://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/TablesWikipediaEN.htm#namespaces) and you need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F

Answer (score 2):

For starters this might be too big a demand on the wikimedia servers. There are over a million categories ([1](https://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/TablesWikipediaEN.htm#namespaces)) and you need to read [Wikipedia:Database download - Why not just retrieve data from wikipedia.org at runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F). You would need to throttle your uses to about 1 per second or risk getting blocked. This means it would take about 11 days to get the full tree.

It would be much better to use the standard dumps at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/ these will be easier to read and process and you don't need to put a big load on the server.

Still better is to get a [Wikimedia Labs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Labs) account, which allow you to run queries on a replication of the database servers or scripts on the dumps without having to download some very big files.

---

To get just the economics categories then its easiest to go via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Economics this has [1242](https://tools.wmflabs.org/enwp10/cgi-bin/list2.fcgi?run=yes&projecta=Economics&quality=Category-Class) categories. You may find it easier to use the list of categories there and build the tree from there.

This will be better than a recursive approach. The problem with the wikipedia category system is that it is not really a tree, with plenty of loops. I would not be surprised if you keep following categories you will end up getting the most of wikipedia.

Comment: Hey, I just need it for the root category "Economics"

Comment: I've updated the answer. For projects related to one subject area its going to be easier using the associated project. See my amended answer.

Comment: Can I use somethings similar to API sandbox in the website - https://tools.wmflabs.org?

Comment: For tools you get access to the database dump files. These are xml files which can be processed quite easily with a python script.

Comment: You can also get access to a database replica where you can run SQL queries. There is lots of documentation on the website. So you can access all the data that that you would via the API but its in different formats.